# Is there a Canon/Legend explanation of the symbols on two vessels inside the Tantive IV?

Tags: star-wars, spaceship, object-identification

All these years I've been wondering about the meaning of these two polygonal symbols painted on the vessels or tanks located in the room where Vader chokes Captain Antilles, at the beginning of *Star Wars: A New Hope (1977)*. The logic dictates that they are signs that represent what is contained inside the containers, but to me, they also suggest something else, like pieces of a Tangram. I have been playing around with them and my best explanation is that they are a hidden logo of the starship's name. Putting together the two symbols, one above the other, I get the letter T but depending on the point of view, someone could say that it is the shape of a robot or perhaps a hidden clue? Anyway, I ask if someone out there have noticed these symbols and have a possible/potential Canon/Legend explanation for their existence in the Star Wars Universe. Thanks.

[image: Still picture of Star Wars: A New Hope]
[image: Still picture of Star Wars: A New Hope]
[image: Two symbols from Tantive IV tanks]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

These symbols are identified in the [*Star Wars: Incredible Cross-Sections*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Incredible_Cross-Sections) factbook (and canonised in the [*Star Wars: Complete Vehicles* (2018)](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Complete_Vehicles_(2018)) book).

The two images in your question are the Atmosphere Substation and the Power Substation.

[image]

Comment: These also appear in _Republic Commando_ on an _Acclamator_-class Republic ship, so it makes sense they wouldn't be specific to the Tantive IV.

Comment: Is there an explanation for these symbols in (Disney) Canon, or just in Legends Canon?

Comment: @nick012000 The same explanation is present in _Complete Vehicles_, a canon reissue of the _Incredible Cross-Sections_ books.

Comment: Thanks again, Valorum for your answer. Stay safe. We need you.